# Http post request to a Django webservice (need login info) using Postman

Tags: django, web-services, postman

I want to send a http request to a webservice ,which I implemented earlier, that need the user to be login. Now, I implemented a form page that do this for me and I need to change it for every different request.

As far as I know, Django need "csrftoken" and "sessionid" to allow requests. Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to add this two field to Postman client and interact with my Django services.

Comment: Is I'm not understand or everyone not understand... To get the best results can you provide some code then ask what to do next with that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postman receives cookies from chrome and you can retrieve them using the Postman interception plugin.
[See here](http://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture)

Now after installing the plugin :

1. Create a new environment so environment variables can be stored
2. Create a method with a test to store the XSRF cookie value in an environment variable, in the test tab post this code

   ```
   var token = postman.getResponseCookie("XSRF");
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xsrf-token", token .value);
   ```

Now you will have an environment variable with xsrf-token in it.

3. Save your method

Create the new post and add XSRF-Token-Header Key in the header.

Access the token value with {{xsrf-token}}

Now before running your new request make sure you run the method, so that it can store the environment variable, and then when you run the actual request it will append its value in the header.

> You can also refer this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-read-cookie-value-postman-request-chaining-ishan-girdhar-oscp).

**Just in case** : For *ajax* requests you can refer to the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _interception did not send data to history_ ?

Comment: tnx for your help.

Comment: Welcome @SeyedHasanMousavi , I'm glad it helped :-)