# When tested http POST with chrome POSTMAN, it doesn't work in django

Tags: python, django, postman

I use `Django 1.9.7 & Python 3.5`

I implement creating user mechanism and tried to test with POSTMAN(chrome application), but it doesn't work and it shows something like belows:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /timeline/user/create/
```

This is the code :

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
From. import views

app_name = 'timeline'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex) /
    url(r'^$', views.timeline_view, name='timeline_view'),

    # ex) /user/create
    url(r'^user/(?P<method>create)/$', views.user_view, name='user_view'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

from timeline.models import *


def timeline_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')


def user_view(request, method):
    if method == 'create' and request.method == 'POST':
        print("hi")
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, password=password)
        user.first_name = request.POST.get('name','')
        user.save()
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        return HttpResponse('create success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('bad request', status=400)
```

`POSTMAN` :
[image]

I tried [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set) but I think this post is for past version.

Comment: you have defined username twice...password not even once

Comment: Django needs CSRF token to allow requests and Postman doesn't add it in the header until implemented. Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158742/http-post-request-to-a-django-webservice-need-login-info-using-postman/38161448#38161448) for adding csrf token in the request header. Also POST is all what is needed, why _create_, until required for something specific.

Comment: Please read this [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/). By default django will protect any POST request. Also you can just use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

for **testing** i used the @csrf_exempt decorator.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def user_view(request, method):
    ...
```

now you should be able to call this function without the csrf cookie.

(last time i tried it, i was using **django 1.8.7**)

source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#edge-cases

Comment: This doesnt solve the issue that the question asked about. More of a work around.

Comment: this is the reason i wrote "for testing ..."

Answer (score 1):

You should put `CSRFToken` in request headers.
After sending request via postman, look at the response `Cookies` section, take csrftoken value and put in `Headers` section of request, like this:
key:`X-CSRFToken`
value: `jSdh6c3VAHgLShLEyTjH2N957qCILqmb  #your token value`

Comment: It said "No cookies were returned by the server"..?

Comment: @user3595632 looks weird, can you check cookies in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Is it possible to check localhost test in dev tools? it doesn't show anything?

Comment: @user3595632 sure you can

Answer (score 1):

> **Sometimes Version problem in 'Postman' :**
>
> I have face the same problem. While sending the data using the oldest version of postman in POST method.
>   That time I have received the empty json data in server side.
>   And **I have fix this problem**, Once I uninstall the oldest version of postman and installed with latest version.

Comment: Suddenly started to raise error, being all config well, in other computer was working well, reinstall dont work for my I think due installed same version but i installed chrome version and work well, maybe is something of cookies cached but i don't understand it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this below statement on top of each and every view function definition (views.py). We don't need to use CRF related statements.

```
@api_view(["POST", "GET"])
```

eg:

```
@api_view(["POST", "GET"])
def GivenInput():
   return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Note*:
But I didn't know that any alternative way to make it global throughout the file.